# Active Admin - filter by presence of has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a `User` model that has_many photos. I'm looking to set up a checkbox filter in Active Admin to filter those users who have photos. Basically where the photos association is present.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos
end
```

Is there an easy way to do this? I know you can filter by users who have a certain photo etc. but I haven't seen an example where you can filter by presence.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finding the correct incantation of Ransack search methods is tricky. To search where the `photos.id IS NOT NULL` can be accomplished with the following filter:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  # Filter users where photos.id is not null
  filter :photos_id_not_null, label: "With Photos", as: :boolean 
end
```

Comment: Does not work for me, generated sql is strange (double where clause with a double negation)

Comment: With a slight modification I was able to get this to work. In my case, my relationship is `has_many :signatures`. This Active Admin config allowed me to toggle on and off with the relationship presence: `filter :signatures_id_null, label: 'Without Signatures', as: :boolean`

Answer (score -2):

Solution that work for me :

Insert in model :

```
ransacker :has_photos do |parent|
  Arel.sql("(select exists (SELECT 1 FROM photos WHERE photos.parent_id = parents.id))")
end
```

Then use it in activeadmin filter :

```
filter :has_photos_true, as: :boolean
```

Find [ref-1](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/using-ransackers#8-testing-for-the-existence-of-a-row-in-another-table-via-a-join) & [ref-2](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/3712#issuecomment-68191434).

Another version if you have a counter cache:

```
ransacker :has_photos do |parent|
  Arel.sql("#{parent.table.name}.report_files_count > 0")
end
```