# ActiveAdmin filter: a has_many: through attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, activeadmin

I want to filter an ActiveAdmin table on an attribute of a model that is linked through a has_many :foo through: :bar relationship.

For example, if a Book

```
has_many :borrowers, through: :book_checkouts
```

...how do I add a filter option on the ActiveAdmin page for Books to let the user filter on the borrower_id? (As a string; Our library has so many borrowers that using a Select here is unwieldy.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Background

In your ActiveAdmin page, you can add filters like so:

```
filter :column_name_1
filter :column_name_2
```

So you'll create a create a new filter statement for `borrowers`, but default, it will create a select.

```
filter :borrowers
```

---

### Solution

So in order to tell it that you don't want to use a select, you have to modify the symbol you give it with what column in the association you want to filter by. So if you want to filter by the ID of the borrowers, you'll do this:

```
# You specify as: :numeric to so ActiveAdmin knows to add 
# filtering options for numbers. So when it renders on the page,
# for the filter option it will display three options to filter by:
# ID equals, is greater than, or is less than

filter :borrowers_id, as: :numeric
```

If you want to filter by another column that's a string, like a `name`, for example, you'll do the following:

```
filter :borrowers_name, as: :string
```

*Note*: I also noticed that is you don't specify the `as: :type` then ActiveAdmin won't recognize the filter and won't render anything for it.

Assisted by answer from question: [Active Admin - filter by presence of has_many association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27797869/active-admin-filter-by-presence-of-has-many-association)